# Marking notifications as unread

Tags: cyanogenmod, notifications

(I use CyanogenMod 9.)

Here's something that bugs me.

Say that someone sent me a few text messages or left a few missed calls on my phone. I see them as notifications, which is great because it draws my attention to them as something I need to take care of.

But, once I tap the notification to see the text messages or the people who called, the notification is cleared. Sometimes I just want to look at them but still leave them for myself to deal with later.

The way this is done in emails is to mark emails as unread; you can read an email, then mark it as unread so you'll know you still need to handle it. I'd love to have something similar for Android notifications, or any other good solution to this problem.

Comment: Sounds less like you want to mark notifications as unread, and more like you want to mark text messages as unread. Question; does CM support tasks? on my HTC phone with Sense, I can turn any e-mail, text or social update into a task, which then organizes them in one place so I can easily come back to them later.

Comment: No, marking text messages as unread does not solve my problem because unread text messages do not get my attention. I never go into the SMS app to check for them. I rely on notifications.

Comment: I don't know of a single Android GUI layer/launcher that treats notifications as anything more than what they are; quick status updates that something happened in the background or while you weren't actively using your phone. Once you've seen them they've served their purpose. Some SMS apps can display a "persistent notification" as long as there are unread messages in your SMS app; that's app-dependent. Others show you that you have unread or new messages with something in their app/widget icon, with or without a notification (persistent or otherwise).

Comment: Yet another reason to move to CM10 - expandable notifications: you can pull down individual notifications for additional details without the need for dismissing them.

Comment: Sounds good, I think I'll upgrade :)

Answer (score 3):

Its worth upgrading to cyanogenmod 10+
With it you can expand notifications to 'preview' the contents of the text or missed call, straight from the notification drawer. To do this, you simply pinch the notification and it will expand down. Try searching youtube for a video demonstration of this, it is a cool feature that will appear to solve your problem.